# Freebase: Asynchronous calls in a for loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, freebase

I need to do n queries to `freebase` depending on the types an entity has.

For example, if got the types in a previous query and I do:

```
for (var n=0;n<types.length;n++) {
subquery(types[n]);
}   

function subquery (typid) {
query = [{
    "schema": {
        "id": typid,
        ... etc ... }
}]

$.getJSON(service_url + '?callback=?', params, function(response) {
    '... etc...';
}
}
```

But before the first `$.getJSON` responds, the second for loop is executed. I can't imagine the solution, although I read a lot of information about asynchronous calls.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var n=0;n<types.length;n++) {
  subquery(types[n]);
}
```

The above code will call a subquery and each subquery call will immediately finish because $.getJSON function does not interrupt the workflow.

After the above code executes what you have is, types.length times of ajax requests started nearly on the same time and there always will be a race conditions on them.

One approach is to use jquery deferred objects, which solves exactly the condition you describe, read more at [Using Deferreds in jQuery 1.5](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/using-deferreds-in-jquery)